# Mock function call within another function call in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

How to mock the following statement :

```
int var = func1(func2(obj.func3()));
```

Expecting the entire result to be mocked to return some value to var

Comment: Mock it piece by piece

Answer (score 2):

Mock it piece by piece, for example:

```
when(obj.func3()).thenReturn(someValue);
when(func2(any())).thenReturn(someValue2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way?

```
Mockito.when(obj.func3()).thenReturn(value);

Mockito.when(func2(value)).thenReturn(value2);

Mockito.when(obj.func1(value2)).thenReturn(int);
```